# writing the vector map to a file in Omnetpp

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, operator-overloading, omnet++

I am having problem in writing the vector map to a file. I would like to know the detail value inside the wsmdata.  I know that inorder to access the detail information I need to use operator overloading like “std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, map& );” in header file as well as in .cc file. But I don’t know how to use it in detail to access the vector data or output the vector data in the file. I have bee stuck in this problem for a long time. Can anybody help ?

Here is the portion of codes:
.h file:
    using std::map;

```
typedef std::vector<WaveShortMessage*> WaveShortMessages;
std::map<long,WaveShortMessages>    receivedWarningMap;
```

.cc file:

```
// add warning message to received messages storage
 receivedWarningMap[wsm->getTreeId()].push_back(wsm->dup());
std::cout<<"Wsm dup() values/ receivedWarningMap="<<wsm->dup()<<endl;
std::ofstream tracefile;
tracefile.clear();
tracefile.open("traceFile1.txt", std::ios_base::app);
for (UINT i = 0; i < receivedWarningMap[wsm->getTreeId()].size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << receivedWarningMap[wsm->getTreeId()][i] << std::endl;

            EV<< "MyID="<<getMyID()<< "Recepient ID"<<wsm->getRecipientAddress()<<"Neighbor ID="<< wsm->getSenderAddress()<< std::endl;
```

}
    tracefile.close();

Comment: It is hard to understand what your goal is. Can you provide a minimal example of file contents and some pseudo-code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all define operator `<<` for your class `WaveShortMessage`, for example this way:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, WaveShortMessage * wsm) {
    os << "Recepient ID=" << wsm->getRecipientAddress() << "; ";
    os << "Neighbor ID=" << wsm->getSenderAddress() << "; ";
    // and any other fields of this class
    //...
    return os;
}
```

Then use the following code to write map to text file:

```
// remember to add this two includes at the beginning:
// #include <fstream>
// #include <sstream> 

std::ofstream logFile;
logFile.open("log.txt"); // if exists it will be overwritten 
std::stringstream ss;
for (auto it = receivedWarningMap.begin(); it != receivedWarningMap.end(); ++it) {
    ss << "id=" << static_cast<int>(it->first) << "; wsms=";
    for (auto it2 : it->second) {
        ss << it2 << "; ";
    }
    ss << endl;
}
logFile << ss.str();
logFile.close();
```

Comment: Thank you Jerzy D. It works well. I want to know how to rebroadcast the accumulated message to the neighbor nodes.  Here we just accumulate and output in the file but I also want to resend/broadcast  the accumulated messages. HOw can I achieve this?

Comment: Which structure would you like to send to neighbours? `OMNeT++` has an opportunity to use own C++ structures in messages, and your goal may be easy to achieve. However, according to Stackoverflow rules you should ask a new question, because this question concerns the writing to file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will post this issue as a new question hope to get reply from you soon.